# generating one single view without ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm working on a app where the backend is rails and the frontend is completely written in ember.js. As soon as you hit the site the index page is already ember.

I now need to make an api in order to share a part of my site through an iframe, and I can't seem to generate only that page without the whole ember application getting in the way. I always get the part that I'm generating for the api, but underneath starts the index page of the ember application.
I don't want the ember app for that part at all.

I've tried to setup a different namespace in my rails route in order to separate both, but that doesn't work correctly. Funny thing is that I also have railsadmin included and that one does work correct, i.e. I don't see the rest of my ember app after every railsadmin page.

My routes.rb

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  root :to => 'application#index'

  namespace :api do
    resources :share_part, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use different layouts.. I think you are only using one layout and within this the complete asset pipeline js code incl. the ember js is loaded? check out your html source in the browser and you will see the loaded js files.

simple use an other layout or an "if single page not include all js" for your single view and do not include the whole js. your rails_admin engine has his own layout and his own js code..that´s the reason why it works there.